# Cannot access shared folder on network using TP-Link wireless adapter

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp

I have a domain controller for 20 LAN PCs using Windows XP, and, on it, a shared folder accessible through `\\192.168.0.12\myfolder`. LAN IP ranges from `192.168.0.100 - 120`
Next, I have a Cisco Linksys router configured using IP `192.168.1.1`, DHCP enabled.

Now I have 5 PCs with TP-Link wireless network adapter installed and connected using my router's connection, and getting IP addresses from the router.  Problem is I cannot access my shared folder when I enter `\\192.168.0.12\myfolder`.

I disabled the firewall and anti-virus on the PC and it connects, but keeps disconnecting every 3 minutes or so with a `Windows cannot access \\Myfolder...`  etc., etc. No network path was found with an `Error Code 0x80004005: Unspecified error`.

Comment: Can you disable the antivirus altogether for a test? Is that antivirus by chance Symantec?

Comment: It's Avira. I have in fact uninstall it temporary for now and windows firewall turned off but still won't access the share folder

Answer (score 0):

Your router has DHCP server on 192.168.`1`.1
shared folder is on 192.168.`0`.1  If the PC you use to access folder uses different IP range, this can be the source of your issues.

Comment: Ok what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Should yuo set default gateway to 192.168.0.1 for all tplinks?